# Instantiate child object from parent class

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

i'm trying to generate some JSON using JSON.Net from 2 classes. Below is an example of the JSON

```
{
  "UserToken" : "string",
  "MyProject" : 
  {
    "MyProjectId" : "string",
    "ProjectId" : "string",
    "ContactId" : "string",
    "DisplayOrder" : "int"
  }
}
```

and here is the C# Classes

```
public class MyProject
{
    public string MyProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ContactId { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string UserToken { get; set; }
    public MyProject MyProject { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see the "RootObject" contains a "MyProject" object, but i cant work out how to instantiate this so i can pass in values like:

```
RootObject o = new RootObject();
o.MyProject.MyProjectId = "something";
```

i've tried searching through forums but all the requests i get are for Lists - which i could use to solve the problem, but i figured there was a gap in my understanding!

Thanks in advance,
J

Comment: You have to assign `object` of MyProject to `o.MyProject` first.

Comment: You can either use the singleton pattern to have one instance of MyProject that self initialises or you need to initialise it manually such as o.MyProject = new MyProject(); else MyProject will be null. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff650316.aspx should interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `RootObject` definition to

```
public class RootObject
{
     public RootObject() {
          this.MyProject = new MyProject();
     }
     public string UserToken { get; set; }
     public MyProject MyProject { get; set; }
}
```

or change the code

```
RootObject o = new RootObject();
o.MyProject.MyProjectId = "something";
```

to

```
RootObject o = new RootObject();
o.MyProject = new MyProject();
o.MyProject.MyProjectId = "something";
```

The problem with the code as it stands is the o.MyProject is not instantiated.

Comment: thats done it! i was thinking it had something to do with inheritance, i.e. i would need to make the rootobject the base class. Very simple solution! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the parent object but you'll also need to create the child object, otherwise you'll get a null reference exception.

```
RootObject o = new RootObject();
o.MyProject = new MyProject();   // <<<THIS
o.MyProject.MyProjectId = "something";
```

or you can use [object initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) like this:

```
RootObject o = new RootObject
{
    MyProject = new MyProject
    {
        MyProjectId = "something",
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of `MyProject` and assign it to `public MyProject` of `RootObject()` class.

```
RootObject o = new RootObject();
MyProject mp = new MyProject();
mp.MyProjectId = "something";
o.MyProject = mp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follows.

```
public class MyProject
    {
        public MyProject()
        {
          this.MyProjectId =string.Empty;
          this.ProjectId =string.Empty;
          this.ContactId =string.Empty;
        }

        public string MyProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ContactId { get; set; }
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {

        public RootObject()
        {
          this.MyProject =new MyProject ();
        }

        public string UserToken { get; set; }
        public MyProject MyProject { get; set; }
    }
```